# Really laggy response on iOS when tapping on input field in bootstrap

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, safari

This has been bugging me for several days with no solution in mind, when I tried tapping on any input fields in iOS safari, it literally takes a minute before the keyboard pops up.

I have tried everything, setting the viewport, disabling zoom, removing all the extra javascript to the bare minimum, still it is happening. Strangely this does not happen when I tap on a textarea, only on text input.

Does anyone have any idea what would cause this?

Comment: That's a pretty vague question without some code to go with it. Is it one page in particular on a certain site or all pages on all sites?

Comment: I am really sorry if this sounds vague, here is my site https://cloud.colmoclub.com. You can already see the effects on the login page, when tapping on the input field, it takes a minute before the keyboard comes up on iOS. This happens to the rest of the input fields throughout the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I just found the solution. Apparently safari on iOS will act wonky when you are running https without a proper certificate. Once I signed the certificates for my subdomains everything appears to be silky smooth now. It's really weird, as I do not expect https to affect form elements in the website.